# Is it possible to override sonar.modules in the sonarqube gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to set up sonar analysis across a non-standard multi-project directory structure with a root project to aggregate all the sonar data.

Using sonarqube runner, I've tried to set the property *sonar.modules* with all the sub-projects (which are not in child directories), but the plugin seems to override the property with erroneous default values that cause my build to fail.

The overwrite seems to happen in this java class : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-gradle/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin.java on line 190.

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried, but looking at how other properties(sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion) within the same [addGradleDefaults method](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin.java#L178) are begin set, Did you try the same pattern followed for configuring the other properties per SonarQube plugin documentation ?

FYR, Here is the link from SonarQube on How to use the plugin and or override the default values within the gradle build script. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle

Here is the code snippet

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "My Project Name"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:java-gradle-simple"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this from my custom plugin and didnt have success yet.

Comment: This answer does not seem to address my problem.  I solved my problem by using Jenkins instead of Gradle to run the sonarqube analyzer. The Jenkins plugin, unlike the gradle plugin, does not overwrite any of the property values I give it.